# move_base and hector_slam

Tags: slam, navigation, odometry, hector-slam, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi , i am working on a mobile robot with ROS , and i want to have navigation ability without any odometry data from my motors . hector_slam is run very good and i have no problem with it , i can get pos and yaw of my robot with a hokuyo laser sensor . the map is published to /map topic .

for navigation and planning i want to use the move_base without map_server and AMCL . i dont have any odom topic .

what is the launch file for do this exactly?
what is the param config for move_base , because there is no update for costmaps from rviz ?! ... i seems its not get my /map topic for calculations... ? ( global_cost_map is STATIC , local_cost_map is not STATIC and windowing is enabled !? .

1 ) how can i send /map to move_base ?
2 ) why we need odom tf ( odom => base_link ) ?
3 ) is odom topic necessary for move_base?
4 ) what is paramers config for move_base for dynamic SLAM navigation ?
5 ) what is a launch file for this to get worked ?

thx for any reply :) .... i just confused a bit :( .

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/166566/move_base-and-hector_slam/) by [edwin](https://answers.ros.org/users/18151/edwin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2014-05-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2014-05-19**:
What version of ROS are you using? Can you post what configuration you're already using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi David , i am using hydro , i solved my problem by publishing a fake optometry data using hector_slam position . only the speed of robot is computed from robot encoders .

now my robot can navigate and follow the trajectory path to rich the goal . i don't use static map ( map server and amcl ) so for both local and global parameters , i set the static parameter false and windowing is true .

---

Originally posted by [edwin](https://answers.ros.org/users/18151/edwin/) with karma: 36 on 2014-05-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0